# Sending requests to webpages using Python's urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I am interested in using Python to automate certain tasks.  Specifically, I would like to use Python to interact with website to perform tasks such as getting specific information from a page, make request (POST data and read the response), and downloading and uploading files.
So far, I have only been able to use Python to get the HTML from a page using urllib2.  The next thing I tried was sending a request to a page; I made several attempts, but they all failed.

```
    >>> import urllib2
    >>> import urllib
    >>> url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/"
    >>> values = {}
    >>> values["input"] = "foo"
    >>> data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    >>> request = urllib2.Request(url + "search/", data)
    >>> response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    >>> html = response.read()
    >>> print html
```

The way I understand things so far is that I need to create a dictionary with the names of the fields and the input and encode it with urllib.urllencode(values).  Then I need to make a request with urllib2.Request(theUrlReceivingTheRequest, data, headers) which, if only given a url will only GET, but, if given data, will POST, and can be given headers that can disguise the program as a common browser such as Firefox or IE.  I then get a response with urllib2.urlopen(request) which returns a file like object which, consequently, I can read().  As I understand it, I can also use urllib2.build_opener() which can receive handlers (that can process cookies, redirrections, authentication etc) and add headers using .addheaders("User-Agent", "").  I'd like to be able to eventually do (and understand) all of these things, but, first, I'd just like to get a form submitted.
In the above code from my interactive session with Python, did I follow the correct procedure?  (I was attempting to input a search for "foo" in the search field on the front page of stackoverflow.)

Comment: What specifically is not working for you? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 7):

Your life will be easier if you use [requests](http://python-requests.org) instead of urllib2.  Here is your example with the requests API:

```
import requests
r=requests.post("http://www.stackoverflow.com/search/",data={'input':'foo'})
print r.text
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the search result using GET method, you can inspect the html code of the FORM:
    `<form id="search" action="/search" method="get" autocomplete="off">
                    <div>
                        <input autocomplete="off" name="q" class="textbox" placeholder="search" tabindex="1" type="text" maxlength="140" size="28" value="foo" style="width: 200px; max-width: 200px; ">
                    </div>
                    </form>`

The action is "/search" the input name is "q", so the request url will be https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=foo

So just use urllib2 to open the url above will work.

You don't need to worry about the request headers like "User Agent" as urllib2 will add that for you, however, you can [set it explicitly](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html).

To make it work, you need to change the "input" to "q" and don't use the "data" parameter in the request, otherwise it will use POST other than GET, the program will be:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/"
values = {}
values["q"] = "foo"
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
request = urllib2.Request(url + "search" +"?"+ data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
html = response.read()
print html

enter code here
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I must look at the page's source and find the "<form id=..." and where it says "action=..." I append that to the end of the current url.  Then I find the "<name=..." and use that as the key in the dictionary which I then encode with urllib.urlencode().  Then the final url is http://www.example/<action>?<encoded data>.  Is that right?

Comment: What if it is a login page and I need to send the username and password?  Wouldn't I have to send an actual request with POST or what if I needed to fill out a form that returned data?  (I have even seen some pages with forms that return results without changing the url of the actual page, how do I use Python to access those sites?)

Comment: Yes, you are right, check the "method" in the form. Normally searching will use GET, and login will use POST. For POST request, use the `urllib2.Request(url, data)`, urllib2 will POST the "data" to the url handler.

Comment: OK, I ran into a problem.  Encoding the data and appending it to the end of the url with a action/?key=item worked _to fill out the fields_; however, the form remained unsubmitted.  Do I need to include something extra for submission.  The tag is similar to <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="form" class="submit" />.  So its type is submit and its name is form.  Do I need to add something like &form=submit to the end?  I tried it and it still wasn't submitted?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more detail of the form? or just past the html code of the Form.